# How to insert parameters into requests.post function properly?

Tags: python, api

```
r = requests.post(
    "http://shop.digiseller.ru/xml/shop_categories.asp",
    data={'seller\id': 479531, 'category\id': 0}
)
```

r.text

the output is: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><digiseller.response><retval>-1</retval><retdesc>отсутствует или неверно задан параметр seller/id</retdesc></digiseller.response>` ( smth like nonexistent or incorrect parameter seller/id )

What is going wrong?
In the API docs of digiseller.ru it is said that names of the paramateres must be wriiten in this way: "category\id", "seller\id". 
I had tried to use  slashes '/' instead of  backslashes, but it didn't work.

Here is an example of a request in the API:

```
<digiseller.request>
  <seller>
    <id>479531</id>
  </seller>
  <category>
    <id></id>
  </category>
  <lang></lang>
</digiseller.request>
```

Comment: Can you link to these API docs? Also why is this question tagged `r`?

Comment: Here it is https://my.digiseller.ru/inside/myshop.asp?view=xml 
but you had better use google translate since it's in russian. Thank you for reply

Comment: According to the example request I'd guess that the JSON format should be data={'seller': {'id': 479531}, 'category': {'id': 0}}
but that doesn't help either :/

Comment: Your example of an API is in XML. Your request is in application/x-www-form-urlencoded. Does the API doc say that it supports form data?

Comment: Aside: https://api.digiseller.ru/ exists, and uses REST and JSON. Does it work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should submit your request as an XML request. Try this:

```
import requests

x = '''<digiseller.request>
  <seller><id>{seller_id}</id></seller>
  <category><id>{category_id}</id></category>
  <lang></lang>
</digiseller.request>'''

r = requests.post(
    "http://shop.digiseller.ru/xml/shop_categories.asp",
    data=x.format(seller_id=7, category_id=0),
    headers={'Content-Type': 'application/xml'})

if r.ok:
    print ('GOOD', r.text)
else:
    print ('BAD', r.text)
```

Result:

```
('GOOD', u'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><digiseller.response><retval>0</retval><retdesc></retdesc><categories></categories></digiseller.response>')
```

Comment: I've tried using http://shop.digiseller.ru/xml/shop_products.asp
and a bit different xml format and it worked smoothly.